# Comportamentos diferentes entre beeline e hive-e

Tags: hadoop, hive

Na execução de comando usando a conexão via beeline sempre funciona, porém com o hive-e não funciona.

Assim funciona:

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://aaats879454co.sistema.br:10000/sistema tez.queue.name=Desenvolvedores -n usuario01 -e "show databases";
```

Porém assim não funciona:

```
hive -e "show databases";
```

Answer (score 0):

Para a versão do Hive 1.1.0 a execução funcionou corretamente.

Importante saber a versão do seu hive, para isso execute:

> hive --version

Pode ser que o serviço do Hive esteja com problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que a intenção  maior de quem pergunta é ter comandos curtinhos, sem burocracia. Respondendo a esse tipo de intenção: **crie um alias para cada comando longo e frequentemente utilizado**.

Bom lembrar que comandos do tipo `beeline` e `hive` são executados com as permissões e configurações desejadas de cada usuário, em particular a string de conexão JDBC define qual serviço Hive usar e a *queue* define qual fila (yarn) usar.

---

Num Cluster Hadoop usual os usuários são criados num servidor de borda, onde cada um é "dono do seu pedaço", podendo ao menos criar seus próprios nomes de comando. Apesar de toda diversidade do mundo Linux, é também comum o ambiente aceitar o arquivo `.bashrc`.

Sugiro fortemente editar esse arquivo com os aliases desejados, **por exemplo:**

```sh
 alias bl="beeline -u jdbc:hive2://aaats879454co.sistema.br:10000/sistema tez.queue.name=Desenvolvedores -n usuario01";

 alias bl_exe='beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://aaats879454co.sistema.br:10000/sistema" tez.queue.name=Desenvolvedores -n usuario01 -e';

 alias bl_exe_csv='beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://aaats879454co.sistema.br:10000/sistema" tez.queue.name=Desenvolvedores -n usuario01 --silent=true  --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV=";" -e';
```

Aí voce pode executar sem burocracia no terminal:

```sh
bl # comando que simplesmente entra no modo interativo do Beeline
bl_exe "show databases"  # fica no terminal e  gera o show tables
bl_exe "SELECT 1+1" # fica no terminal e  gera resultado de query
bl_exe_csv "SELECT 123 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 456" > lixo.csv # resultado de query em CSV
```