# Transformar uma consulta no HIVE em arquivo .CSV

Tags: banco-de-dados, hive

Preciso extrair informações do HIVE ou Hue gerando um arquivo CSV , já tentei alguns comandos tanto pelo Hive como pelo aplicativo Hue mas sem sucesso. Alguém já fez algo semelhante?
Antecipadamente, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme lembrado [por esta resposta Wiki](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/482970/4186), o comando `beeline` permite fazer a consulta e gerar o resultado em CSV.

Voce pode "guardar uma colinha" para copia/cola ou (sugiro fortemente) manter um nome de comando padronizado no seu arquivo `.bashrc` (ver link indicado). **Por exemplo:**

```sh
 alias bl_exe_csv='beeline -u "jdbc:hive2://aaats879454co.sistema.br:10000/sistema" tez.queue.name=Desenvolvedores -n usuario01 --silent=true  --outputformat=dsv --delimiterForDSV=";" -e';
```

Aí voce pode executar sem burocracia no terminal:

```sh
bl_exe_csv "SELECT 123 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 456" > lixo.csv
```